# How to read content of [object Object] in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I currently send a delete request from my client (React application) to the Express server:

```
axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/users/logout', {
  headers: {
    accessToken: auth.accessToken,
    refreshToken: auth.refreshToken,
  }
});
```

When I log the `req.headers` on my Express server I get the following:

```
  refreshtoken: '[object Object]',
  accesstoken: '[object Object]'
```

I do have the express json and urlencoded middleware enabled.

**TL;DR:** How can I read the data of the received object [object Object] on my Express server?

Comment: clientside check contents of `auth.accessToken`, then in node use utils.inspect or trusty JSON.stringify(req.headers, null, 2).. in node a console.log() will only go 3 levels before [object Object] is shown in place of further nested values.. i.e you need do more debugging

Comment: What do `auth.accessToken` and `auth.refreshToken` contain? Are they strings or objects? You need to send string values.

Comment: You are sending JSON object, you must send String.

Answer (score 0):

Problem as suggested by some responses: auth.accesToken where `null`. After debugging and actually sending truthy values in the headers, everything works fine.

As always 'check yourself before wreck yourself'.